# show inner div overflow:visible of parent overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

How do you make the inner div visible when the parent of the inner div is `overflow:hidden`?
I need to make the parent or slides to be `overflow:hidden` because there are multiple slides that need to be hidden. But what I want is to show part of the inner "slide" when showing to break out of the overflow. How do I do that or if I need to redesign it how should it work If you can please leave me an example of what todo thanks.

```
<div id="slides" style="overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:300px">
    <div id="slide" style="height:300px; height:300px">            
        <div style="overflow:visible">
            <img alt="" src="image.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Too many words, jsfiddle my friend, jsfiddle.

Comment: you missed semicolon in inline style.

Comment: Just reading the title, I think its impossible, the parent is `overflow:hidden;`, whatever is going to leave its boundaries will be hidden, whatever is inside it will be shown, unless, you put the parent inside a parent div with a position relative, then place that thing you wanna show as a sibling absolute div.

Comment: @ Devang Rathod End of inline CSS semicolon is not necessary.

Comment: Short answer - you can't, but I'm still having a hard time trying to understand the effect you want to achieve. Can you rephrase or elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this demo

`[parent div overflowhidden inner div overflow scroll][1]`
http://jsfiddle.net/fGFnu/1/

Comment: I tried that and it makes no difference if you can give an example on jsFiddle of it working that would be cool

Comment: That gives me scroll bars and that doesn't look right i want my image to pop out of the hidden part Im using javascript aswell. Basically I animate the left position out then which then shows the image but I want the end part on the right to be outside of the hidden part